# Can CRM Online 2013 use the CRM 2015 Email Router?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, email-router

Currently I'm using Microsoft Dynamics® CRM Online Spring '14
(6.1.3.119) (DB 6.1.1.1847) and we have installed the CRM Email router 2013, we are planning to upgrade to Dynamics CRM 2015.

Can I upgrade the CRM Email Router 2013 to 2015 while using Dynamics CRM Spring 14?

I found a link to do that(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531069.aspx#BKMK_Upgrade2013) but it doesn't say if is backwards compatible also the link to downoad the Email Router 2015 says you need "Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015" https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting for some help I decided to answer my own question by installing  the Email Router Versoin 2015 from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45017 in a new server, I pointed one of the profiles to CRM 2013 and the result was:

**"Incoming Status: Failure -The Email Router service that is installed is not a supported version. The Email Router version is later than expected by  the Microsoft Dynamics CRM server at https://...organization".**

Confirmed Email Router is not backwards Compatible with Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online.